# How to merge two Firebase auth accounts?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase auth. I have an user who has signed up with both their Google & Github account as separate users. Now they are asking to merge their accounts. How do I do that?

Comment: What exactly is the end result of this merge?  There's no Firebase API you can simply invoke to make this happen, as there could be way too many points of conflict that would have to be manually resolved.  You'll also have to manually figure out what to do with any storage from other Firebase and Cloud products associated with those accounts.

Comment: You need to provide more information on how you want to merge accounts. Is this a user initiated action or admin initiated? Normally you want to verify the 2 users are the same before merging. How do you establish this? Do they have the same email? More information would be helpful.